# What is sb protocol and how is works internally?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I have configured a notification hub using Azure portal for implementation of push notifications for mobile apps. On navigating to the Access Policies section, I see couple of policies with names: DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature and DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature as shown in the below diagram. Both the policy names contain connection string. One of the connection string is as follows:

Endpoint=sb://expedia.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=JnVgQvxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy1HgWUfUo=

I want to understand what is **sb** protocol here and want to how it works internally and does it depends on HTTPS.

I have to access the above endpoint from a remote server. How to consider the above while white listing the proxy rules to allow access to the above endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sb is just an endpoint schema that we understand, and it's not an actual protocol.  The actual protocol is https.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Turns out sb means "Service Bus" and it appears to basically be Webhooks as a Service...

Comment: do you have Microsoft documentation for this? I can't find it.

Comment: It's interesting to note that sb is also used for Azure Event Hubs, when creating the connection string for example.

Comment: can we connect to it without using Azure specific libraries?

Answer (score 0):

According to a more broadly framed Service Bus FAQ, they detail the ports that are used by sb:// which uses both HTTPS (443) and AMQP (5671, 5672)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq#what-ports-do-i-need-to-open-on-the-firewall--